# JQPlot Date range too large even with x-axis max set

Tags: javascript, jquery, timestamp, jqplot

I'm  trying to plot this data with JQPlot.  The first number is the timestamp.

`[[[1452228073000, 5323]], [[1452228073000, 371], [1452832774000, 279]], [[1762228073000, 550], [1463719273000, 494]]]`

Here is my plot function:

`var chartObj = $.jqplot('chart',  dataArray , {
                title: title,
                axesDefaults: {
                    tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
                    pad: 1.2
                },
                axes:{
                    xaxis:{
                        renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                        label:"Time",
                        tickOptions: {
                            formatString:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
                            min: new Date(window.minTime),
                            max: new Date(window.maxTime),
                            angle: 30
                        },
                    },
                    yaxis: {
                        renderer: $.jqplot.LinearAxisRenderer,
                        min: min,
                        label: units
                    }
                },
                cursor:{
                    show: true,
                    zoom: true
                },
                legend:{
                    show: true,
                    placement: "outside",
                    labels: dataTypes
                },
                seriesDefaults: {
                    showMarker: false,
                    lineWidth:1,
                    yaxis: 'yaxis'
                }
        });`

The min and max date bounds are correct for the data given but when I plot the data the X-axis extends way further into the future.

[Here is what the graph looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odkbL.png)

My largest date is ~2020 but the graph extends to 2072

Comment: well, yeah, your `1762228073000` value corresponds to November 3rd, 2025... The graph is correct - your data is probably mangled.

Comment: The graph goes to 2072. I was just tested a wide range of data.